# my hash of jquery is not working correctly

Tags: jquery, google-visualization

Iwant to draw a graph but the hash loop is not sending properly so it will not generate any graph.

The object that I use is giving `[undefined]` and nothing.

```
jQuery.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: url,
  data: {},
  dataType : 'json',
  success: function(result){
    result =result['stats'];
    jQuery(".historical_stats").show();            
    var options = {
      colors: ['#8FB82B', '#FFC514', '#757575'],
      chartArea: {width: '100%', top: '5%'},
      legend: {position: 'top'},
      vAxis: {textPosition: 'in'}
    };
   /* Hourly stats */
    dayStats = [];
    jQuery.each(result['today_labels'], function( index, value ) {
      obj = [value['label'],value['value']];
      dayStats.push(obj);
    });
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
     data.addColumn('string', 'Hour');
     data.addColumn('number', 'Served');
     data.addRows(dayStats);
    new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.
      getElementById('sntq-day-chart')).draw(data,options);
```

Comment: Could you post all your code, or if there's a lot a small version that replicates the issue. What's the value of `url`? What are you expecting `result ` to look like? etc.

Comment: url is the path where i want to send it i want a hash like [   ['Mushrooms', 3],
          ['Onions', 10],
          ['Olives', 10],
          ['Zucchini',10],
          ['Pepperoni', 2]]

Comment: `[ ['Mushrooms', 3], ['Onions', 10], ['Olives', 10], ['Zucchini',10], ['Pepperoni', 2]]` isn't a hash. It's a array of arrays and you won't be able to access it like `result['stats']`. To use as you have the returned JSON should look more like `{ 'Mushrooms': 3, 'Onions': 10, 'Olives': 10, 'Zucchini':10, 'Pepperoni': 2}`.

Comment: ["7pm", "8pm", "9pm", "10pm", "11pm", "12am", "1am", "2am", "3am", "4am", "5am", "6am", "7am", "8am", "9am", "10am", "11am", "12pm", "1pm", "2pm", "3pm", "4pm", "5pm", "6pm"] if have this kind data and i want like this [["7pm",1] ["8pm", 3],["9pm",2]] so do you have any suggestion for this

Comment: Can't do it with that example. Where are you getting the numbers for the second values in the sub arrays? Could you update your question stating exactly what your problem is. With a real example of the data you're trying to use. If the problem you're experiencing is limited to the `success` callback then please limit your code example to just the callback function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using the google map api it would accept the data in the format only in the form of array of array  so try to make it like this
as your code says you are taking a hash of result so by using the java script make it as array of array then it will works